# ListView with images with different height coming from network causes "flickers"

Tags: android, performance, listview

Here's the scenario: I've some info to show on a ListView. Every row can have, title, body, date, avatar, and more data. And a ImageView that comes from network. The ImageView has a different height on every row. I know what will be it's height in px once downloaded.

What I'm doing right now is to adjust the width of the image to fill it's parent, and auto adjusting the it's height automatically.

I'm loading a fixed placeholder while the image is downloaded.

Here's the code of the ImageView:

```
public class ResizableImageView2 extends ImageView {

public ResizableImageView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    Drawable d = getDrawable();

    if(d!=null){
        // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }else{
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
}
```

The problem is: The placeholder is loaded with a fixed size, and once downloaded we put the ImageView, the layout recalculates it self, and that causes wasted cpu, slow scrolling.

I'm already pre-caching the incoming rows to "minimize" this problem. This way the app loads an image from disk/memory 80% of the time (if you are in a good network and you scroll in a normal speed) and the listview does not "flicker".

The solution I'm searching is to preset the size of the placeholder at the same size that will be the downloaded image. But for some reason I'm having a hard time doing this.

I can make a little cropping of the image (some small pixels) if needed, but nothing as make all the images croped at the same size :P

Ideas? examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally for me the solution was:

```
public class ResizableImageView2 extends ImageView {

private int fixedHeight = -1;
private int fixedWidth = -1;

public ResizableImageView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e("ResizableImageView2", "onMeasure called!");

    if (fixedHeight != -1 && fixedWidth != -1) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) fixedHeight / (float) fixedWidth);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {
            // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}

public void setFixedHeight(int fixedHeight) {
    this.fixedHeight = fixedHeight;
}

public void setFixedWidth(int fixedWidth) {
    this.fixedWidth = fixedWidth;
}
```

I can set the height and the width before downloading the bitmap with setFixedHeight and setFixedWidth. The place holder should be a 9 patch for better stretching. and at the layout I've android:scaleType="fitXY".

With this I can pre-set the size of the imageview before downloading it, and once downloaded the image view will fill the width and have a height with the correct aspect ratio.